# Any Yahoo YUI validation framework that I can implement in asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation, yui

Has anyone seen a [Yahoo YUI](https://yuilibrary.com/) validation framework that I could implement into asp.net MVC?  I've seen a [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) one but I want to work wit YUI.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite as spiffy (IMO) as jQuery, but here's a [yazaar validation framework](http://yazaar.org/examples/extras/jc21/validate.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that Microsoft have announced they'll be shipping [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) with Visual Studio and there will be more integration with the MVC framework. This may or may not affect your decision to use [YUI](https://yuilibrary.com/).

More details here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [yui-form-validator](http://code.google.com/p/yui-form-validator/) on Google code...

It looks promising for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [indputEx](http://javascript.neyric.com/inputex/). Hope it helps.