# Has anyone build form validation using YUI?

Tags: validation, yui

**DUPE: [Any Yahoo YUI validation framework that I can implement in asp.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93664/any-yahoo-yui-validation-framework-that-i-can-implement-in-asp-net-mvc)**

Has anyone built form validation functions using YUI that could mimick how asp.net handles form validation?

I know jquery has a nice validation addon, was hoping YUI would also.

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93664/any-yahoo-yui-validation-framework-that-i-can-implement-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YUI doesn't have form validation built in as a separate component.  There are a number of loose add-ons that people have done over the years, such as:

http://blog.jc21.com/2007-02-05/yui-unobstrusive-javascript-validation/
http://bubbling-library.com/eng/api/docs/plugins/wizard

The most directed work I've seen on this in the YUI ecosystem has been this project:

http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/05/08/inputex/

I'm not sure what its current state is.

We'll add a formal component to YUI that provides common forms functionality, but that's down the road a bit.

-Eric

Answer (score 2):

I just took a quick look through the YUI toolkit and there doesn't seem to be anything that jumps out at me.  I know they have stuff for validation on the DataTable inputs, but it doesn't look like there is an equivalent for forms.

Comment: Why was this voted down?  It's good manners to point out in the comments why you voted something down.